# VBA to display pasted html data as table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a form in Excel using VBA that will allow me to paste some html data (a table of grant requests) into a text box, be able to click a button and have it output showing the table data as a table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For context, we have a pretty poor system at work for dealing with grant requests and it shows all of the information as html data, without the html, head and body tags, so it just shows up as code. I'm not in a position to have the system changed so am wanting a tool that we can paste the table code into and have it output in a message box as a proper table.

Comment: Other than your code attempt, you have to show us a sample of the "html data" as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.